# how can I grab email one by one come from gmail using oauth 2.0 via JS code

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0

I had retrieve the gmail contacts using JS code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var clientId = '';
      var apiKey = '';
      var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly';
      $(document).on("click",".googleContactsButton", function(){
        gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
        window.setTimeout(authorize);
      });
      function authorize() {
        gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthorization);
      }
      function handleAuthorization(authorizationResult) {
        if (authorizationResult && !authorizationResult.error) {
          $.get("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/thin?alt=json&access_token=" + authorizationResult.access_token + "&max-results=500&v=3.0",
            function(response){
              //process the response here
              //console.log(response);

              var response = (JSON.stringify(response.feed.entry[1].gd$email, null, 4));
console.log(response);
            });
        }
      }
    </script>
```

now my problem is this I am grab any one email by passing no. in

```
(JSON.stringify(response.feed.entry[1].gd$email, null, 4));
```

after `entry[0 or 1 or etc]`

and result of above code is `[
    {
        "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other",
        "address": "ashish.ascent@gmail.com",
        "primary": "true"
    }
]`

I want to retrieve all the email one by one how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding the `JSON.stringify()` for now, you may be able to do the below.

The `Array .map` method returns a new array.

```
var arrayOfEmails = response.feed.entry.map(function (feedEntry) {
  return feedEntry.address;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
function(response){
   //console.log(response.feed.entry.length);
    for(var i = 0;i<response.feed.entry.length; i++){
    if(response.feed.entry[i].gd$email)
    {
        console.log("email is " + response.feed.entry[i].gd$email[0].address);
    }
}
});
```

after receiving the response print the email one by one using for loop till the response having emails